# Hide form after submit with php / html

Tags: php, forms

I know there are some very similar questions around here but since I am not that deep into javascript / ajax etc. yet, I couldn't solve my problem with the answers I found there.

I have a contact form on a website that I want to hide on submit.

My HTML is:

```
<form method="post" id="contact" class="peThemeContactForm form" action="mail.php">
    <div id="personal" class="bay form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls name">
                <h2>Name</h2>
                <input class="required span9" type="text" name="author" data-fieldid="0" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls email">
                <h2>Email</h2>
                <input class="required span9" type="email" name="email" data-fieldid="1" id="email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls message">
                <h2>Message</h2>
                <textarea name="message" rows="12" class="required span9" data-fieldid="2" id="comments"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls send-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="contour-btn red buttoncontact">Send Message</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notifications">
        <div id="contactFormSent" class="formSent alert alert-success">
            <strong>Mail sent</div>
        <div id="contactFormError" class="formError alert alert-error">
            <strong>No mail sent</div>
    </div>

</form>
```

And my PHP file is

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $mailTo = "mymail@provider.com";
    $subject = "Contact Request";
    $body = "You've got mail
<br><br>
FROM: ".$_POST['email']."<br>
NAME: ".$_POST['author']."<br>
COMMENTS: ".$_POST['message']."<br>";   
    $headers = "To: Me <".$mailTo.">\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$_POST['author']." <".$_POST['email'].">\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";
    $mail_success =  mail($mailTo, utf8_decode($subject), utf8_decode($body), $headers);        
}

?>
```

Could anyone please tell me the easiest way to hide the form after someone has submitted? I don't know much about java or jquery yet, so a basic or step by step answer would be appreciated. :)

Thanks!

EDIT: The contact form is on the same page where I want to hide it. There is no other page, it's just the one.

Comment: I wouldn't invest looking into Java - think you mean Javascript.

Comment: The input form is not hidden because you do not throw an other page at the end of your PHP file (the email bit) So at the end do a `header('Location: index.php'); exit;` for example to load the homepage

Comment: Indeed I do :) Fixed that

Comment: I'm sure you mean [tag:JavaScript] not [tag:Java] ?

Comment: I do not want to go to another page after submit, just hide the form itself since it is only one page I post content on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can add this JavaScript code in the end of your HTML:

```
<script>
   $(function () {
        $('#contact').on('submit', function (e) {
            var self = this; //Keep a reference to the form that was submitted
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'), 
                method: $(this).attr('method'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function () {
                     $(self).hide(); //Hide the form if the request was successful 
                },
                error: function () { alert('Failed to send email'); }
            });

        });
   });
</script>
```

This should submit the form via ajax and not refresh the page when that happens.

Comment: I do use jQuery. Where exactly would I need to add this in the html file, just anywhere? I tried some options but so far it didn't do anything for me. Thanks already though! :)

Comment: Under the `</form>` should work, but really anywhere should be fine. the `$(function () { ... })` part ensures that this is ran when the page elements are loaded

Comment: I tried and it doesn't give any errors but the form also doesn't hide. Is there anything I need to replace in the snippet?

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors? Check your browser console and let me know

Comment: You were right, there totally were errors! With all the testing around, I had a typo that made my library not load. But now it worked and the form completely disappeared! :) Thanks so much! Now I just got to find out how to place different content to display then and I am good. :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery in your project, just make a

```
$("form").hide();
```

after the submit action.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need JavaScript for this.

Since you mention that the PHP for dealing with the form submit is on the same page as the HTML, you can simply tell the code not to render the form when the form was posted back, by wrapping the form inside a PHP `if` statement, something like this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['email'])){
?>
  <form method="post" id="contact" class="peThemeContactForm form" action="mail.php">
  <!-- (and all the rest of your form code...) -->
  </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

P.S. You could also consider adding an `else` in which you print something else such as a "Thanks" or other kind of confirmation message.

Comment: The php is a single .php file, the html is on my index.html. How would I implement the code you posted then?

Comment: in the question you specifically stated that they were in the _same_ file. You said you only had one page. Sorry if I misunderstood your wording. If that's not the case, what is your code doing now? It seems it will post from index.html the mail.php and then you're just left with a blank page? Unless you missed out some code?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood. I stated about the one page cause I thought another answer given above wanted me to just redirect to another page after submit. The Contact Form is on a long website with sliders, which is why it's all the same page. My code is in several files. I'm sorry that I am so clumsy about this. A bit in over my head here. :)

Comment: If I try to add your code bit to my html, it complains that html can not execute this so I think I am doing it wrong

Comment: that's because a .html file does not get processed by PHP. And besides, it's now clear that you submitted the form to the separate URL called mail.php, so it won't run any code located anywhere else. Can I ask again...what does your code do now after it submits to mail.php? Unless you either a) already have some JavaScript to make it submit via AJAX or b) have some more code in mail.php which prints some output or redirects the user elsewhere,  then you should just be left with a blank page

Comment: On clicking the submit button, an email gets sent and the website displays the text from the contactFormSent div. So the user stays on the same page with the data he just entered, but the "Mail sent" text appears. There is also not more in the php file

Comment: There is a rather large form.js in my files, but it contains a lot of functions and I just copied it there from another resource for testing. Maybe I got some beginners luck getting this to work at all and now I dont get what I did. :D

Comment: Looks like you already have some JavaScript and an AJAX call then. Otherwise your browser would automatically redirect your whole screen to the "mail.php" URL. You need to find out what JavaScript is executing when you submit the form, and change it so it hides the form instead of displaying the message. Your browser's Developer Tools can help you with this task - by listing what events exist on an element, and letting you step through the JavaScript as it executes.

Comment: I think so too, I am looking into it and I will try to understand better whats going on. Thanks for your detailed help and patience! :)